# Ошибка с grub при запуске - error: uncnow filesustem

Tags: linux, grub

Однажды на HDD я установил Linux Mint, а после решил поменять его на Debian, и из за спешки и глупости решил быстро ликвидировать Linux Mint просто удалив содержащий его раздел. Так у меня вышел один раздел со своими файлами и 300 ГБ свободного места, в это свободное место я поставил Debian выделив 100 GB под систему и 1 для подкачки, а также в установщике Debian загрузил GRUB в этот HDD.

Но в момент загрузки Debian с этого диска я получил ошибку на экране:

```
error:  unknow filesystem.
Entering rescue mode...
grub rescue>
```

На сколько я понял, GRUB из Linux Mint не нашел саму систему, из за моего грубого удаления её.
Подскажите как можно исправить эту ошибку, возможно как то до-настроить GRUB что бы он определял систему?
Заранее спасибо.

Comment: Выхлопы `sudo fdisk -l`, `sudo blkid` сюда.

Comment: don Rumata, спасибо вам за ответ, но к сожалению при вводе этих команд выходит ошибка говорящая что команда не найдена: `Unknow command 'fdisk' такая же ошибка к суперпользователю sudo.

Comment: Ну т.е. загрузиться с какого-нить livecd ты тоже не можешь?

Comment: don Rumata, Мне нужно поставить именно на жёсткий диск

Comment: Ну с таким подходом тут тебе никто не поможет. И не только тут.

Comment: @Innokentie, это неважно на жёсткий или нет. Если сам не понимаешь и хочешь помощи - делай что тебе говорят.